# GoJS: Prevent movement of diagram on dragging a node to boundary

Tags: gojs

On dragging a node towards view port boundary, diagram starts moving. Is there a way to prevent this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

That automatic scrolling that you are seeing is called "autoscrolling". You can disable it by setting https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#autoScrollRegion to zero.

```
$(go.Diagram, . . .,
  { . . .,
    autoScrollRegion: 0
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(go.Diagram, . . .,
  { . . .,
    "panningTool.isEnabled": false,
  })
```